# How to simplify my YAML CircleCI configuration for better readability?

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, yaml, devops, circleci

I am pretty new to continuous integration, so far I like it very much. I am wondering if there is by any chance a possibility to make the configuration file better readable and simplified.

The reason why I am asking is because of the fact that I am using the same Workflow for **Development** and **Production** mode.

How can I keep the configuration "DRY" without copy-pasting the same configuration file over and over again?

Can I do something with BASH script instead?

My config:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  production:
    working_directory: ~/production-theme
    docker:
    - image: circleci/node:10.16
    steps:
    - add_ssh_keys:
        fingerprints:
        - xxx
    - store_test_results:
        path: test-results
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
        name: Restore Yarn Package & Packge.json Cache
        keys:
        - yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
        - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        - yarn-packages-
        - v1-dependencies-
    - run:
        name: Install Yarn Packages
        command: yarn install
    - run:
        name: Building Repo In Production Mode
        command: yarn prod-build
    - save_cache:
        name: Save Yarn Package Cache
        key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        paths:
        - ./node_modules
    - run:
        name: Run SSH keyscan
        command: ssh-keyscan ${hostname} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - run:
        name: Install Rysnc
        command: sudo apt-get install rsync
    - run:
        name: Upload files to theme folder
        command: rsync -avP --delete-before --exclude 'node_modules' --exclude '.git'
          --exclude 'webpack' --exclude '.circleci' --exclude 'src' --exclude '.babelrc'
          --exclude '.browserslistrc' --exclude '.eslintrc' --exclude '.gitignore'
          --exclude '.prettierrc' --exclude '.stylelintignore' --exclude '.stylelintrc'
          --exclude 'env.json' --exclude 'package.json' --exclude 'yarn.lock' --exclude
          'README.md' ~/production-theme ${username}@${hostname}:/var/www/html/${site_name}/wp-content/themes/
  development:
    working_directory: ~/develop-theme
    docker:
    - image: circleci/node:10.16
    steps:
    - add_ssh_keys:
        fingerprints:
        - xxx
    - store_test_results:
        path: test-results
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
        name: Restore Yarn Package & Packge.json Cache
        keys:
        - yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
        - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        - yarn-packages-
        - v1-dependencies-
    - run:
        name: Install Yarn Packages
        command: yarn install
    - run:
        name: Building Repo In Develop Mode
        command: yarn test-build
    - save_cache:
        name: Save Yarn Package Cache
        key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        paths:
        - ./node_modules
    - run:
        name: Run SSH keyscan
        command: ssh-keyscan ${hostname} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - run:
        name: Install Rysnc
        command: sudo apt-get install rsync
    - run:
        name: Upload files to theme folder
        command: rsync -avP --delete-before --exclude 'node_modules' --exclude '.git'
          --exclude 'webpack' --exclude '.circleci' --exclude 'src' --exclude '.babelrc'
          --exclude '.browserslistrc' --exclude '.eslintrc' --exclude '.gitignore'
          --exclude '.prettierrc' --exclude '.stylelintignore' --exclude '.stylelintrc'
          --exclude 'env.json' --exclude 'package.json' --exclude 'yarn.lock' --exclude
          'README.md' ~/develop-theme ${username}@${hostname}:/var/www/html/${site_name}/wp-content/themes/
workflows:
  version: 2
  production_and_development:
    jobs:
    - development:
        filters:
          branches:
            only: develop
    - production:
        filters:
          branches:
            only: master
```

Comment: You could try YAML references and anchors, which allow you to define a YAML section and then reuse it. It's part of the YAML spec, rather than it being a CircleCI thing. The YAML parser in use in CircleCI does appear to support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could utilise the "commands" and "executors" keys of CircleCI config.

More here: 
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/reusing-config/#the-commands-key
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/reusing-config/#executors

Applying it, your config could become a lot more readable and a bit shorter.

Wrap the docker definition inside "executors":

```
executors:
  node:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.16
```

All the step definitions are combined under `commands: flow: ...`. Meanwhile the `jobs` become quite slim, as they'll reuse the "flow" `command`:

```
jobs:
  production:
    executor: node
    working_directory: ~/production-theme
    steps:
      - flow:
          environment: "production"
          yarn: "yarn prod-build"
```

**UPDATED `.config.yml`:**

```
version: 2.1

executors:
  node:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.16

commands:
  flow:
    parameters:
      environment:
        type: string
        default: "production"
      yarn:
        type: string
        default: "yarn prod-build"
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - xxx
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-results
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          name: Restore Yarn Package & Packge.json Cache
          keys:
            - yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - yarn-packages-
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Install Yarn Packages
          command: yarn install
      - run:
          name: Building Repo
          command: << parameters.yarn >>
      - save_cache:
          name: Save Yarn Package Cache
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
      - run:
          name: Run SSH keyscan
          command: ssh-keyscan ${hostname} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - run:
          name: Install Rysnc
          command: sudo apt-get install rsync
      - run:
          name: Upload files to theme folder
          command: rsync -avP --delete-before --exclude 'node_modules' --exclude '.git'
            --exclude 'webpack' --exclude '.circleci' --exclude 'src' --exclude '.babelrc'
            --exclude '.browserslistrc' --exclude '.eslintrc' --exclude '.gitignore'
            --exclude '.prettierrc' --exclude '.stylelintignore' --exclude '.stylelintrc'
            --exclude 'env.json' --exclude 'package.json' --exclude 'yarn.lock' --exclude
            'README.md' ~/<< parameters.environment >>-theme ${username}@${hostname}:/var/www/html/${site_name}/wp-content/themes/


jobs:
  production:
    executor: node
    working_directory: ~/production-theme
    steps:
      - flow:
          environment: "production"
          yarn: "yarn prod-build"


  development:
    executor: node
    working_directory: ~/develop-theme
    steps:
      - flow:
          environment: "develop"
          yarn: "yarn test-build"

workflows:
  version: 2
  production_and_development:
    jobs:
      - development:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: develop
      - production:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Please note, that I've just modified your config, but haven't tested it, so minor typos might be present.

Comment: Hi Mv! Thank you very much for your help and advice. I have tried but I get the following error on run.

[#/jobs/production] expected type: String, found: Mapping
# |   |   Job may be a string reference to another job

   |   |   2. [#/jobs/production/steps/0/flow] no subschema matched out of the total 2 subschemas
# |   |   |   |   1. [#/jobs/production/steps/0/flow] expected type: Mapping, found: Sequence

Comment: Hello are you there?

Comment: @Galanthus Please check the updated code above. After double checking with CircleCI docs, it appears that invoking reusable commands with parameters must use "object" syntax, rather than "array". Note the updated definitions inside "jobs/production/steps" and "jobs/development/steps".